# Dropdown list change based on other dropdown list in details view ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, dropdown, detailsview

I have two dropdown lists in a detailsview one called College and the other is Department. If the user select a college, the department dropdown list should generate all the departments for the selected college.

Here is the detailsview and the dropdown lists:

```
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="600px" AutoGenerateRows="False" CssClass="table table-bordered mtop" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnDataBound="DetailsView1_DataBound">
                <FieldHeaderStyle CssClass="DetailsViewHeader" Width="200px" />
                <Fields>

                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="College" SortExpression="Colleges">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="ArName" DataValueField="Code"></asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenColl" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("Colleges") %>' /> 
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Colleges") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="ArName">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="ArName" DataValueField="Code"></asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenDep" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("ArName") %>' />                       
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ArName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                   <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                            &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                            &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" Text="Delete"  OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete ?');" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ControlStyle CssClass="btn-login" />
                        <ItemStyle CssClass="text-center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>

           </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>
```

Here is the SqlDataSources:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UEDConnectionStringMarwaMarwa %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ArName], [Code] FROM [College]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UEDConnectionStringMarwaMarwa %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Code], [ArName] FROM [Department] WHERE ([CollegeCode] = @CollegeCode)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DetailsView1$DropDownList2" Name="CollegeCode" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is the error message:

> Could not find control 'DetailsView1$DropDownList2' in
>   ControlParameter 'CollegeCode'

I did this `DetailsView1$DropDownList2` so it can access the dropdown list that is inside the detailsview

What is the problem ?

Comment: Set Autopostback=true on your first dropdown list, and you may need to have the sql datasource inside edit item template

Comment: Also this looks like a nice clean example of cascading dropdowns for template controls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749944/implementing-cascading-dropdownlist-binding-in-a-templated-control

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with the `DetailsView` and not experienced with the `SqlDataSource`, but I will try to help.

In my experience, I have learned that you shouldn't try to assume a control's `ClientID`. So, first I would recommend getting the `ClientID` from the server control.
Using an inline expression, I would try something like this:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID='<%= DetailsView1.Rows(0).FindControl("DropDownList2").ClientID %>' Name="CollegeCode" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
```

For more about asp.net inline expressions see [Introduction to ASP.NET inline expressions in the .NET Framework](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976112).

Because I am unfamiliar with the `DetailsView` control, I don't know if there will be a row at index 0 in the `DetailsView` when it executes this inline expression (which would throw an exception).

If that code doesn't work, I would suggest dynamically setting the `ControlID` on the back end that executes after the `DetailsView1` rows are bound (such as inside the `DetailsView1`'s `DataBound` event method).

**VB:**

```
If DetailsView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Dim objDropDownList2 as Control = DetailsView1.Rows(0).FindControl("DropDownList2")
    If objDropDownList2 IsNot Nothing Then
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("CollegeCode").ControlID = objDropDownList2.ClientID
    End If  
End If
```

**C#:**

```
if (DetailsView1.Rows.Count > 0) {
    Control objDropDownList2 = DetailsView1.Rows(0).FindControl("DropDownList2");
    if (objDropDownList2 != null) {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("CollegeCode").ControlID = objDropDownList2.ClientID;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!